# How to return one object for related objects in a QuerySet?

Tags: django

To show objects that change dramatically over time, I decided to create them as separate objects with a related field, like:

```python
class Desktop(models.Model):
    related = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
    date_from = ApproximateDateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_to = ApproximateDateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

In my template I then have a dropdown of date ranges to access changes over time, even though the dropdown options actually go to separate (related) objects.

The problem is, in other views I want to show objects of a certain type, but I'm only interested in the original object of each related set. So where

```
desktops = Desktop.objects.filter(type=desktop_type)
```

gives me

```
DesktopA 2003 2009
DesktopA 2009 2013
DesktopA 2013 2015
DesktopB 2003 2015
```

I want

```
DesktopA 2003 - 2009
DesktopB 2003 - 2015
```

But the names sometimes differ over time. The only field that indicates the relation is the related field. I think I need something like

```
desktops = Desktop.objects.filter(type=desktop_type).exclude(related__date__from__lt=F('date_from'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That actually just works.

```python
from django.db.models import F

desktops = Desktop.objects.filter(type=desktop_type).exclude(related__date__from__lt=F('date_from'))
```